# Why should i create node_modules folder for nodejs dependencies for each expressjs app

Tags: python, ruby, node.js, express, module

I really don't get it. When i run npm install on the main folder, why does it have to download all the dependencies in the node_modules and why does this need to be done for each single project? In Sinatra(Ruby microframework), I never had to do this and it is easy to use the gems that are installed globally without having to download and save each one of them into the project folder again.

I read somewhere that it is done to avoid version mismatch issues but if its working by installing it globally and simply 'require'ing it in many other languages like Python(uses virtualenv to tackle version issues), Ruby etc., why can't it be the same for node.js?

Whatever happened to DRY?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `npm install --global` (or `-g` for short) to install globally. But that creates a problem when 2 projects reference to different version of the same dependency. You will have conflicts that is hard to trace. Also install it locally makes it more portable. You can reference to [this document](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally)

This problem does not only exist in node.js world. Just different language approach this problem differently. I don't know ruby well, but:

1. In python people use `virtualenv` to separate dependencies, which needs more effort.
2. Maven of Java will cache artifacts in `$HOME/.m2` folder, but when compile the projects, they will copy those bytecode from .m2 folder to a local folder `target`.

There is time you want to do `npm install --global` though for those tools such as `grunt.js`/`gulp.js`.

I just think it has nothing to do with DRY, because you didn't write code twice. It's just downloaded twice.

That being said, you still can install everything globlally.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Leonmax. Although i can install globally, the node_modules folder still gets saved into the project folder again right?

Comment: so it's the folder that makes you feel uncomfortable? it's like target folder of maven, in python you'll get lots of *.pyc too, there is always something other than the source code itself, isn't it? Why it bothers you so much, LOL